# Printing Start/End time and Service Name in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that stops a service and creates .log file in a folder. Now, in a log file there should be stop date/start date and stop time/start time of service and a service name. How can i do that?

```
@echo off
sc stop tapisrv
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
pause
if exist "C:\AliCanDirik" echo A file name AliCanDirik already exists in 
directory C:\
if not exist "C:\AliCanDirik" mkdir C:\AliCanDirik
echo AliCanDirik is created in directory C:\
echo %UserName% > odev.log
pause
```

I changed it like this;

```
@echo off
sc start tapisrv
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
pause
sc stop tapisrv
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
pause
if exist "C:\AliCanDirik" echo A file name AliCanDirik already exists in 
directory C:\
if not exist "C:\AliCanDirik" mkdir C:\AliCan
echo AliCanDirik is created in directory C:\

set logfile=C:\AliCanDirik\odev.log
echo Service name= tapisrv Date= %date% Time= %time% Username= %username% >> 
%logfile%
tapisrv -options oas >> %logfile%
pause
```

it creates file and .log file and getting time&date in .log file. But i need to learn start time and stop time separately.
I guess found it;

```
@echo off
sc start tapisrv
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
set starttime=%time%
set startdate=%date%
pause
sc stop tapisrv
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
set stoptime=%time%
set stopdate=%date%
pause
if exist C:\AliCanDirik (
    echo A file name AliCanDirik already exists in directory C:\
)else (
    mkdir C:\AliCanDirik
    echo AliCanDirik is created in directory C:\
)

set logfile=C:\AliCanDirik\odev.log
echo Service name= tapisrv Start Date= %startdate% Start Time= %starttime% 
Username= %username% >> %logfile%
echo Service name= tapisrv End Date= %stopdate% End Time= %stoptime% 
Username= %username% >> %logfile%
```

pause

Comment: Your code is faulty, `'directory' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Instead of two If's you should use an `if  cond (dothis) else (dothat)` see http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not entirely clear to me what you intend to do.

This batch uses if else and also conditional execution on success `&&` or fail `||` of the previous command similar to evaluating errorlevel.

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\AliCanDirik" (
  echo A file/folder name AliCanDirik already exists in directory C:\
) else (
  mkdir C:\AliCanDirik
  echo AliCanDirik is created in directory C:\
)
set "logfile=C:\AliCanDirik\odev.log"

sc start tapisrv && (
  >> "%logfile%" Echo started Service name=tapisrv Date=%date% Time=%time% Username=%username%
) || goto error
pause

sc stop tapisrv && (
  >> "%logfile%" Echo stopped Service name=tapisrv Date=%date% Time=%time% Username=%username%
) || goto error
pause

Rem afaik tapisrv is a dll, you can't run it this way.
>> "%logfile%" tapisrv -options oas
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's easy. `%DATE%` contains the date, `%TIME%` contains the time and the service is obviously called `tapisrv`. You can combine this information like this: `ECHO %DATE% %TIME% tapisrv`. To write it into the odev.log file you simply add `>>odev.log`. That's it. But beware: `echo %UserName% > odev.log` will always "delete" the old file and create a new one. `>` overwrites the file. If you want to append the text, you should use `>>` instead.

```
@echo off
sc stop tapisrv
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
pause
if exist "C:\AliCan" echo A file name AliCan already exists in
directory C:\
if not exist "C:\AliCan" mkdir C:\AliCan
echo AliCan is created in directory C:\
echo %UserName% > odev.log
ECHO %DATE% %TIME% tapisrv>>odev.log
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried it but couldn't see any .log file in a folder.

Comment: Is there really a line containing only `directory C:\\`? This line should cause an error.

Comment: There is no problem about it. Just need to know time and date separately. I mean start time of tapisrv and end time of tapisrv.